# mp3 file not playing in MediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-8

i just started learning windows 8 phone development form channel 9 video tutorial

when i put Mp3  file in source property of MediaElement it is not being played by my phone

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="-125,110,149,51" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid x:Name="InnerContentPanel"  Grid.Row="5" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <Button x:Name="btnRandom" 
                        Margin="276,203,10,264" 
                        Click="btnRandom_Click" 
                        Content="Get Copy&#xD;&#xA;"
                        Background="Red"
                        />
            </Grid>
            <MediaElement x:Name="meSound"
                          Source="\Assets\Sound\demo.mp3"
                          Volume="13"
                          AutoPlay="false"
                          ></MediaElement>
        </Grid>
```

My code behind Code

```
private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     meSound.Play();
}
```

can anyone tell me why my phone is not playing this mp3?

Comment: try to attach event handler to `MediaElement`'s `MediaFailed` event, see if the event fired and what type of failure you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source URI of `MediaElement` is wrong. It should be `Assets/Sound/demo.mp3`.